# Quitar corriente a Arduino y seguir con la actividad utilizando EEPROM

Tags: c#, arduino

Resumo lo que hace el código actualmente. Ahora mismo tendríamos dos "finales de carrera", un botón de marcha y un botón de paro, y de forma "imaginaria" una cinta transportadora. Entonces cuando estemos en el punto A, se presionaría el botón "final de carrera A" y al darle al botón de marcha pues comenzaría a moverse la cinta transportadora hacia la derecha hasta llegar al punto B, entonces se presionaría el botón "final de carrera B" y al darle al botón de marcha la cinta transportadora iría hacia la izquierda hasta llegar al punto A y repitiendo así el proceso las veces que queramos (el botón de paro haría que se parase todo como su nombre indica). La cosa es ¿Y si se va la luz? en este caso he conseguido que al irse la luz, se guarde la dirección en la que se movía la cinta y al darle al botón de marcha seguiría en esta dirección. Pero lo que me gustaría conseguir es que a la hora que se vaya la luz, cuando vuelva, se guarde la dirección en la que se movía la cinta y que comience a moverse en esta dirección automáticamente. Dejo aquí una muestra del código actual, si alguien me da alguna idea o me menciona alguna otra función que se lo agradecería.

```
#include <EEPROM.h> 

int DireccionEEPROM=0; //Posición de la memoria donde guardamos el dato

byte pinMi=7, pinMd=8; //Salidas para que el "motor" o cinta transportadora vaya a izquierda Mi y vaya a derecha Md
byte pinFb=10, pinFa=11; //pines de entrada, de los finales de carrera punto A y punto B 
byte pinMa=3, pinP=2; //pines de entrada para pulsador de (Ma)rcha y (P)aro

byte motorD=0, motorI=0; // variables para poner el valor de salida inicializados en 0 para evitar problemas

byte memoria=1; // Cuando en la memoria se tenga el valor o dato 1 iremos hacia la derecha, cuando tengamos el valor o dato 2 irá hacia la izquierda

void setup()
  {
    memoria=EEPROM.read(DireccionEEPROM); //Recogemos el calor que hay en la posición de la EEPROM
      if(memoria !=1 && memoria !=2)
        {
          memoria=1; 
          EEPROM.write(DireccionEEPROM,memoria);
        }
    pinMode(pinMi,OUTPUT);//Salida motor izquierda pin 7
    pinMode(pinMd,OUTPUT);//Salida motor izquierda pin 8
    pinMode(pinFa,INPUT);//Entrada final de carrea izquierda, pin 11
    pinMode(pinFb,INPUT);//Entrada final de carrera derecha, pin 10 
    pinMode(pinMa,INPUT);//Entrada pulsador de marcha, pin 3
    pinMode(pinP,INPUT);//Entrada pulsador de paro, pin 2    
  }

void loop()
  {
byte Fb,Fa,Ma,P; //Variables para almacenar valores
    Fa = digitalRead(pinFa);
    Fb = digitalRead(pinFb);
    Ma = digitalRead(pinMa);
    P = digitalRead(pinP);
      if(P==1)
        {
          motorD=0;
          motorI=0;
        }
       else
        {
          if (motorD==0 && motorI==0 && Ma==1) //Si estando parado, se pulsa el boton de marcha "Ma"
            {
              memoria=EEPROM.read(DireccionEEPROM);
              if(memoria !=1 && memoria !=2){memoria=1; EEPROM.write(DireccionEEPROM,memoria);}
              if(memoria==1) {motorD=1;motorI=0;}//Si iba hacia la derecha, ve a la derecha
              if(memoria==2){motorD=0;motorI=1;}//Si iba hacia la izquierda, ve a la izquierda
            }  
              if(motorD==1 && Fb==1){motorD=0; motorI=0; memoria=2; EEPROM.write(DireccionEEPROM,memoria);}//Si va hacia la derecha y llega al final de carrera (Fb=1): para y guarda la memoria para ir a la izquierda
              if(motorI==1 && Fa==1){motorD=0;motorI=0; memoria=1; EEPROM.write(DireccionEEPROM,memoria);}//Si va hacia la izquierda y llega al final de carrera izquierdo (Fa=1) para y guada en memoria para ir a la derecha 
            }
    digitalWrite(pinMi,motorI);
    digitalWrite(pinMd,motorD);        
        }
```

Comment: Edita la pregunta y agrega comentarios explicando que controla cada pin: (motor izquierdo, motor derecho, etc.) para entender mejor la lógica.

Comment: Disculpa que haya tardado tanto en editarla y añadirle los comentarios, no pensaba que alguien me contestase tan rápido, gracias por el consejo, lo tendré muy en cuenta para siguientes preguntas :)

Answer (score 0):

El objetivo es lograr que al reiniciarse Arduino, todo siga funcionando como estaba al momento de cortarse la energía.

El sistema puede estar en tres estado: yendo a la izquierda, yendo a la derecha o parado. Creamos un `enum ESTADO` para documentar la situación actual.

```
enum ESTADO {NINGUNO = 0, IZQUIERDA = 1, DERECHA = 2, PARADO = 3};
byte memoria = NINGUNO;
```

La variable `memoria` parte en `NINGUNO` para reflejar el hecho de que aún no tenemos información sobre el estado. Para inicializarla usamos una función:

```
void recuperarMemoria() {
  byte viejoValor = EEPROM.read(DireccionEEPROM);
  if (viejoValor != IZQUIERDA && viejoValor != DERECHA && viejoValor != PARADO)
  {
    viejoValor = IZQUIERDA;
  }
  establecerMemoria(viejoValor);
}
```

Esta función lee y valida el estado desde la EEPROM. Si el estado no es válido, lo inicializa como yendo a la izquierda.

La instrucción final, `establecerMemoria` se encarga de que el hardware refleje la realidad del estado:

```
void establecerMemoria(byte nuevoValor) {
  switch (nuevoValor) {
    case IZQUIERDA:
      motorD = 0; motorI = 1;
      break;
    case DERECHA:
      motorD = 1; motorI = 0;
      break;
    case PARADO:
      motorD = 0; motorI = 0;
      break;
  }

  if (nuevoValor != memoria) {
    memoria = nuevoValor;
    EEPROM.write(DireccionEEPROM, memoria);
    digitalWrite(pinMi, motorI);
    digitalWrite(pinMd, motorD);
  }
}
```

La función recibe el nuevo estado y programa los motores de acuerdo con ello. Además, si el nuevo estado es distinto al estado anterior, lo graba en la EEPROM y activa físicamente los motores. Debido a que la EEPROM admite una cantidad limitada de escrituras, evitamos escribir en ella a menos que la información cambie.

Con esto, el programa principal queda mucho más simple:

```
void setup()
{
  pinMode(pinMi, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pinMd, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pinFa, INPUT);
  pinMode(pinFb, INPUT);
  pinMode(pinMa, INPUT);
  pinMode(pinP, INPUT);

  // La función requiere los pines ya programados.
  recuperarMemoria();
  // Ahora ya está en movimiento.
}

void loop()
{
  byte Fb, Fa, Ma, P;
  Fa = digitalRead(pinFa);
  Fb = digitalRead(pinFb);
  Ma = digitalRead(pinMa);
  P = digitalRead(pinP);

  if (P == 1) {
    establecerMemoria(PARADO);
  }
  else if (motorD == 1 && Fb == 1) {
    establecerMemoria(IZQUIERDA);
  }
  else if (motorI == 1 && Fa == 1) {
    establecerMemoria(DERECHA);
  }
}
```

Nota: No tengo a mano un circuito para probar, por lo que pueden haber detalles y errores.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, no se como agradecértelo, voy a probar y a adaptarlo y ya comentaré como sale la cosa. De verdad muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Lo que pides que guardes en la EEPROM cuando se vaya la luz, es más bien de electrónica que programación.

Hace años con los PIC y en asm hice un mini proyecto para este tipo de tareas. Puse una fuente de alimentación de 24 VDC como alimentación y que carga un condensador de esa magnitud. Al apagar la luz, se apaga todo los componentes menos el microcontrolador en el cual se quedaba unos segundos activo para que le diera tiempo guardar en la EEPROM todos sus datos. Eso si, tenía un optoacoplador para un pin digital de entrada para avisar al microcontrolador la falta de luz. Ahí te dejo la idea.

Comment: Muchas gracias ^^